# Can't "Click lock to make changes" after update to BigSur

Tags: password, system-settings

After I updated my MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018) to BigSur 11.1 something went wrong.
I can log in, I can change the admin users password, I can access my keychain and I can run `sudo` with no issues.

What I can't do though is to click the padlock to make changes in System Preferences. Even when I enter the correct password the dialog behaves as if I entered the wrong password.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so apparently this was easily solved by resetting the SMC (system management controller)
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/649884?login=true&page=1#618964022

Instructions on how to do this can be found here
https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201295